# how can I hit F2 to delete current line in notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to assign the F2 button to delete the line where the cursor currently is in notepad++. How can I do that?

Comment: Doesn't Ctrl+L meet your needs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete current line and add new line in Notepad++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14299971/how-to-delete-current-line-and-add-new-line-in-notepad)

Comment: No, I want to assign that to F2. And it's not duplicate.

Comment: Have you tried Settings -> Shortcut Mapper... -> Scintilla Command? It's all there on my side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to *Shortcut Mapper* from *Settings* menu, then go to *Scintilla commands*
find *SCI_LINEDELETE* and modify it to what you want.